# how to add profile picture in UserEntity with FosUserBundle

Tags: php, fosuserbundle, symfony

I try to add a profile picture in my user Entity but i fail , i work with symfony 3 and fosuserbundle , for doing this work , I use a listner , here my entire code :
the code of my `UserEntity`:

```
namespace Forum\ForumBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Util\SecureRandom;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class User extends BaseUser

{

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please, upload the product brochure as a PDF file.")
     * @Assert\Image(
     *     
     * )
     */
    private $brochure;

    public function getBrochure()
    {
        return $this->brochure;
    }

    public function setBrochure(File $file = null)
    {
       $this->brochure = $file;

        return $this;
    }

public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
         $this->test = false; 
         //  $this->uploadProfilePicture();
        // your own logic
    }

}
```

My listener :

```
namespace Forum\ForumBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\PreUpdateEventArgs;
use Forum\ForumBundle\Entity\User;
use Forum\ForumBundle\FileUploader;

class BrochureUploadListener
{
    private $uploader;

    public function __construct(FileUploader $uploader)
    { 
        $this->uploader = $uploader;
    }

    public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {die("good");
        $entity = $args->getEntity();

        $this->uploadFile($entity);
    }

    public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();

        $this->uploadFile($entity);
    }

    private function uploadFile($entity)
    {
        // upload only works for Product entities
        if (!$entity instanceof Product) {
            return;
        }

        $file = $entity->getBrochure();

        // only upload new files
        if (!$file instanceof UploadedFile) {
            return;
        }

        $fileName = $this->uploader->upload($file);
        $entity->setBrochure($fileName);
    }
}
```

the listener use Uploader file :

```
namespace Forum\ForumBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

class FileUploader
{
    private $targetDir;

    public function __construct($targetDir)
    {
        $this->targetDir = $targetDir;
    }

    public function upload(UploadedFile $file)
    {
        $fileName = md5(uniqid()).'.'.$file->guessExtension();

        $file->move($this->targetDir, $fileName);

        return $fileName;
    }
}
```

I configure my services as well

```
 app.brochure_uploader:
        class: Forum\ForumBundle\FileUploader
        arguments: ['%brochures_directory%']
    app.doctrine_brochure_listener:
        class: Forum\ForumBundle\EventListener\BrochureUploadListener
        arguments: ['@app.brochure_uploader']
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: prePersist }
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: preUpdate }
```

an I declare the parameter :brochure-directory in config.yml

```
parameters:
    locale: fr
    brochures_directory: 'web/uploads/brochures'
```

the probleme is when I update my entity , the bro

```html
<?php

/*
 * This file is part of the FOSUserBundle package.
 *
 * (c) FriendsOfSymfony <http://friendsofsymfony.github.com/>
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

namespace FOS\UserBundle\Controller;

use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FormEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FilterUserResponseEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\GetResponseUserEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;

/**
 * Controller managing the user profile
 *
 * @author Christophe Coevoet <stof@notk.org>
 */
class ProfileController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Show the user
     */
    public function showAction()
    {
        $user = $this->getUser();
        if (!is_object($user) || !$user instanceof UserInterface) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException('This user does not have access to this section.');
        }

        return $this->render('FOSUserBundle:Profile:show.html.twig', array(
            'user' => $user
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Edit the user
     */
    public function editAction(Request $request)
    {
        $user = $this->getUser();
        if (!is_object($user) || !$user instanceof UserInterface) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException('This user does not have access to this section.');
        }

        /** @var $dispatcher \Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface */
        $dispatcher = $this->get('event_dispatcher');

        $event = new GetResponseUserEvent($user, $request);
        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::PROFILE_EDIT_INITIALIZE, $event);

        if (null !== $event->getResponse()) {
            return $event->getResponse();
        }

        /** @var $formFactory \FOS\UserBundle\Form\Factory\FactoryInterface */
        $formFactory = $this->get('fos_user.profile.form.factory');

        $form = $formFactory->createForm();
        $form->setData($user);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            /** @var $userManager \FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface */
            $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');

            $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
            $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::PROFILE_EDIT_SUCCESS, $event);

            $userManager->updateUser($user);

            if (null === $response = $event->getResponse()) {
                $url = $this->generateUrl('fos_user_profile_show');
                $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
            }

            $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::PROFILE_EDIT_COMPLETED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));

            return $response;
        }

        return $this->render('FOSUserBundle:Profile:edit.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm all out of suggestions. You may need to post another question, and think if there is anything that you may have missed. Sorry, i tried to help out.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing your config.yml to:

```
parameters:
    locale: fr
    brochures_directory: '%kernel.root_dir%/../web/uploads/brochures'
```

Maybe that's the problem? Try it first.

Edit #2.
Secondly can you edit your app/config/parameters.yml and add the following parameter:

```
brochures_directory: uploads/brochures
```

Also make sure you are clearing your cache everytime:

```
php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

See if that works.

Edit #3.
I notice your configuration is quite different than the default, and I was trying to duplicate the setup, but there's a lot of work involved in doing that.

I see a difference in what I use and you use which might also affect the problem you are seeing:

```
parameters:
   locale: fr
   brochures_directory: uploads/brochures
```

So in other words, remove the quotes and get rid of 'web' prefix. Also make sure you have created those folders, both "uploads" and "brochures" under it.

See if this works.

Like I said I tried to duplicate, bu then I get the "Please, upload the product brochure as a PDF file." on the "Register" page, but there would still be quite a bit of work for me to try to duplicate your setup.

I think it's probably something simple, based on the fact I'm getting that message.

Comment: think you for your answer ,Yes I tried , but It is not working

Comment: Hello, I edited my post. Can you try the second suggestion please.

Comment: Hi, think you again for your answer, inforutualy itss not working :( ,the same problem still

Comment: Can you post your controller code where you create the User Entity and upload the picture and persist to the database please. There may be a problem there.

Comment: the controller is in vendor folder, I dont Override It

Comment: I added the controller

Comment: I updated my post. Can you try that one last change. Maybe that is the problem. It's probably something simple.

Comment: Hi, Im trying to run my project , but I have meet some 
inexplicable exception , take a look please :Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException' with message 'Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Forum\ForumBundle\EventListener\BrochureUploadListener::__construct() must be an instance of Forum\ForumBundle\FileUploader, none given, called in C:\wamp\www\forum2\var\cache\prod\appProdDebugProjectContainer.php on line 337 and defined' in C:\wamp\www\forum2\src\Forum\ForumBundle\EventListener\BrochureUploadListener.php on line 14

Comment: Did you change your BrochureUploadListener class at all? You should have this on Line 14: `public function __construct(FileUploader $uploader)`. If not, try clearing your cache: `php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod` and `php bin/console cache:clear` and then run again. It's always wise to clear your cache when you make changes to your files.

Comment: Yes , I have it , and I run the command but the same exception is in my cmd